# Create a working submit button for form to send email

Tags: html, forms, css, html-email

How can I write a code to create a working submit button where somebody click the submit button on my page and that data goes to my working email id for example to `smrithikollam@gamil.com`.

"Not preferring JavaScript.. Prefer to write code in HTML 5 & CSS3 "

---

Here is the HTML code for my form

```
<div id="forms">
    <form class="form">

        <p class="name">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
        </p>

        <p class="email">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" />
        </p>

        <p class="web">
            <input type="text" name="web" id="web" placeholder="9876 543 210" />
        </p>        

        <p class="text">
            <textarea name="text" placeholder="Write something to us" /></textarea>
        </p>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

and Here is my CSS code for submit button

```
.submit input {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #474E69; 
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First: ordinary Forms have action attribute which contains the address of page that receives form data, While your form has not:

```
<form action="sendmail.php">
```

Second: You can not send form using pure html and CSS and you need a serverside language as well as PHP or ASP to receive form data and process them to send as email.

Comment: Thnx dear.. So is it possible to do with .net . If yes my problem will get solved..!!

Comment: Check this code. You have to replace mail body and receiver etc. by data you receive from form: https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/aspnet-c39624/send-an-e-mail-using-aspnet-a604246.html

Comment: Besides, Welcome to stackoverflow.com . You can accept best answer or rank answers using checkmark and top-down arrows beside answers.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is to capture the submit button click and prevent default behavior of the function by returning false. In inside the function capture the form input value and build the body.   activate a link by sending it the mailto as a value for the href.
I have not tested it for the link activation so probably the best to start testing with IE 
Hope this may help
Alan Mehio
London

```
<body>
    <div id="forms" >
<form id="myform" class="form" action="#">

<p class="name">
<input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
</p>

<p class="email">
<input type="text" name="myemail" id="myemail" placeholder="mail@example.com" />
</p>

<p class="web">
<input type="text" name="myphone" id="myphone" placeholder="9876 543 210" />
</p>        

<p class="text">
<textarea name="mytext" placeholder="Write something to us" /></textarea>
</p>

<p class="submit" >
<input type="submit" value="Send"  onClick="sendEmail()"/>
</p>
</form>
    <a id="mylink" href="#"> </a>
</div>
    <script>
    function sendEmail() {
        var  str = "name: " + document.forms.myform.myname.value + "\n" + "email: " + document.forms.myform.myemail.value + "\n" + "phone: " + document.forms.myform.myphone.value + "\n" +
            "text: " + document.forms.myform.mytext.value;      
        var link = document.getElementById("mylink");
        link.href="/mailto:alan.mehio@gmail.com?subject=form submottion&body=" + str;
       clickLink(link);
        return false;
    } 


 function clickLink(link) {

   if (isIE())
   {
      link.click();
      return;
   }
   else if (document.createEvent)
   {
      var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initEvent(
         'click'     // event type
         ,true      // can bubble?
         ,true      // cancelable?
      );
     var allowDefaultAction = link.dispatchEvent(e);           
   }

 }

 function isIE () {
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? true : false;
}

</script> 

</body>
```

Comment: Just to confirm here that javascript can't send an email but rather the above link which get invoked will trigger the default mail client on the user computer with pre-filled data. The user has to send the email via the selected mail client

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code will submit an email to the email you enter instead of user@example.org
(In your case smrithikollam@gamil.com)

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT EMAIL TO: user@example.org"><a href="mailto:user@example.org">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

```
                <div class="col-md-6  col-sm-12" >
                    <h3>Need Help ? Write Us. </h3>
                    <hr />
                    <form>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="3"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you describe why you mean this is the correct answer?